# Are there any touchscreen devices out there that will run Windows Developer Preview?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I'm guessing that a touch based all-in-one would do the trick, but I'm not sure. I, like most folks, have a traditional PC and am itching to try Win8 on a touch device. Something tells me that an iPad won't cut it...

Are there any touchscreen devices out there that will run Windows Developer Preview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as things are, it would need to be x86 based for now (interestingly the developer tools on WDP allow for ARM cross compilation).

If you want to run windows 8 on the same hardware its being developed on, i'd suggest taking a look at [this blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/experiencing-windows-8-touch-on-windows-7-hardware) - it has a list of *everything* that MS is testing the OS on - even old warhorses like the thinkpad x60. In general *any* x86 based tablet you're happy with and meets the system specs (and i've seen WDP run on systems as slow as 1.4 ghz)should work.

So yes, there are.

Comment: Yup. Like the HP Tm2 I'm typing on runs the Dev priview just fine.

Comment: Just because it is in their test lab doesn't mean it will be smoth sailing. I'm on a Lenovo T410S with multi-point touchscreen which is in the list, but the driver isn't perfect. (The touch screen won't work for clicking, but is fine for dragging. Others have reported the same problem.)

Comment: Its the best bet for finding systems that mostly work. I was trying to avoid a "buying recommendation" type answer - and went for a 'you should try here' type answer.

Answer (score 1):

My co-worker has a Acer Iconia Tab W500 that he just loaded Win8 On, and LOVES it.  This tablet also comes with a 'dock' that has a keyboard, pointer mouse, and some additional ports..  I think he said it was under $500

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft gave developers Samsung tablets with W8 Preview at the Anaheim Build Conference, not sure what model it was. 11.6" with Intel processor

It was used in this video, worth watching
http://twit.tv/show/windows-weekly/226

[image]